# Date from Firestore returns null

Tags: angular, date, google-cloud-firestore, angular8

I am trying to get a date from Firestore, but it always returns "null" and I don't know why.

Function:

```
const sub = ref.valueChanges().subscribe(res => {
if (res) {
    console.log(res);
    sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

On Firestore:
[image: Screenshot-2019-09-10-at-23-24-03.png]

In the console:
[image: Screenshot-2019-09-10-at-23-27-34.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue this way: 
Save your date to miliseconds (with getTime() method) and when retrieving the data change it to the date formate you wish. You can even use the pipes from angular to achieve it with minor effort.

Example:

inside the Ts

```
date= 1568154047047; // your date from firebase
```

inside the html

```
{{date | date }}
```

Here is an example using that way. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-el1bxz